# Help correcting bookmarklet to open new Gmail compose window

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to configure a bookmarklet to compose a new message from my Gmail account in a new window. The problem is that I always get a scroll bar on the right hand side. Here's what I'm using right now.

```
javascript:(function(){ window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1','Compose Gmail','status=no,directories=no,location=no,resizable=no,menubar=no,width=600,height=600,toolbar=no'); })();
```

If there are any other things you think should be tweaked, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Either define the height to be taller since the content is taller or don't define the width/height and let it auto size.

Your other option is to open a script page that loads GMail into itself and resizes the window using javascript.

Comment: Changing the height or not defining the window size doesn't do anything. There's still a scroll bar. I think there must be some issue with the link. I've tried messing with it, but I can't figure out all the parameters Gmail is using.

Comment: Upon further review the scrollbar is something you will have to live with as it's being generated by Google and not your window.open. When you open the page the source contains about 5 iframes, one of which contains the actual email input form. That iframe is generating your scrollbar, not your window.open statement. Even if you open GMail directly and in full screen mode you still get the scrollbar.